# Comment Out Link Shows in Webmaster

Tags: robots.txt, crawl-errors, sitelinks

I had "Privacy Policy" link on my old website. When I launched my new website, I put the link in  footer but disallowed that to robots.txt by adding this code:

```
<?php /*?><div class="text-right">
            <a href="http://www.echofreelance.com/terms-and-conditions/">Terms</a> | <a href="http://www.echofreelance.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div><?php */?>
```

After a long time I saw that webmaster tools were showing my privacy policy link under Crawl Errors. I submitted a removal request for this URL. But again this is showing me under Crawl Errors. I have also checked the linked pages. I found no issue. Please help me why this is showing to Google even if I am not allowing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP code isn't modifying the robots.txt file. You've merely commented out the link to the page.

Try creating a robots.txt file in the main public directory of your website. Then add the following:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /terms-and-conditions/
```

You could also add a noindex meta tag to the file in question:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

After you've made the changes above, re-submit the removal request and wait for it to take effect.